# Asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

how to Bind webpages that's already created with a new master page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AT Page_PreInit event you can set master page.

for example

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "Master.master";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the markup in the .aspx file something along the following lines

1) Remove html head & body

2) Insert ASP:CONTENT tag

3) Insert MasterPageFile attribute in @PAGE directive

To be honest the easiest way might be to just create a new content page, select the masterpage and then copy any markup you need into the  panel and copy your codebehind over too.